# How to select two columns to plot with dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

apple is a dataframe whose data structure is as the below:

```
apple
           Date        Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close  
0    2017-01-03  115.800003  116.330002  114.760002  116.150002  114.311760   
1    2017-01-04  115.849998  116.510002  115.750000  116.019997  114.183815   
2    2017-01-05  115.919998  116.860001  115.809998  116.610001  114.764473   
3    2017-01-06  116.779999  118.160004  116.470001  117.910004  116.043915   
4    2017-01-09  117.949997  119.430000  117.940002  118.989998  117.106812   
5    2017-01-10  118.769997  119.379997  118.300003  119.110001  117.224907   
6    2017-01-11  118.739998  119.930000  118.599998  119.750000  117.854782   
7    2017-01-12  118.900002  119.300003  118.209999  119.250000  117.362694   
8    2017-01-13  119.110001  119.620003  118.809998  119.040001  117.156021   
9    2017-01-17  118.339996  120.239998  118.220001  120.000000  118.100822
```

Now i want to select two columns Date and Close ,to set Date as x axis and Close as y axis,how to plot it?

```
import pandas as pd    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
x=pd.DataFrame({'key':apple['Date'],'data':apple['Close']})    
x.plot()   
plt.show()
```

I got the graph such as below.

[image]

The x axis is not Date column !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New `DataFrame` is not necessary, plot `apple` and use parameters `x` and `y`:

```
#if not datetime column first convert
#apple['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(apple['Date'])

apple.plot(x='Date', y='Close')
```

[image: graph]